Trying to make a simple neural network and get a ValueError shapes are not aligned
There is a task at my uni to create a simple (not for me, i guess) neural network that guesses person's sex by given weight and height. Problem is that we jumped to that right after print hello world -ish tasks and I barely understand a thing. After a lot of googling, jumping around, copy/pasting and praying to Guido van Rossum I came up with this:
# Importing the numpy library
import numpy as np

# Function to calculate the sigmoid of a number
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

# Function to calculate the derivative of the sigmoid
def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

# Class representing a neuron
class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, weights, bias):
        self.weights = weights
        self.bias = bias

    # Method to feed forward the inputs through the neuron
    def feedforward(self, inputs):
        total = np.dot(self.weights, inputs) + self.bias
        return sigmoid(total)

# Class representing a neural network
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        # Creating random weights and biases for each layer
        self.weights1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)                   
        self.weights2 = np.random.rand(2, 1)
        self.bias1 = np.zeros((2, 1))
        self.bias2 = np.zeros((1, 1))

        # Creating instances of neurons for each layer
        self.h1 = Neuron(self.weights1, self.bias1)
        self.h2 = Neuron(self.weights1, self.bias1)
        self.o1 = Neuron(self.weights2, self.bias2)

    # Method to feed forward the inputs through the network
    def feedforward(self, x):
        out_h1 = self.h1.feedforward(x)
        out_h2 = self.h2.feedforward(x)
        out_o1 = self.o1.feedforward(np.array([out_h1, out_h2]).T)
        return out_o1

    # Method to train the network
    def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            hidden_layer = sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights1, inputs) + self.bias1)
            output_layer = sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights2.T, hidden_layer) + self.bias2)

            output_error = targets - output_layer
            output_delta = output_error * sigmoid_derivative(output_layer)

            hidden_error = np.dot(self.weights2, output_delta) * sigmoid_derivative(hidden_layer)
            self.weights2 += np.dot(hidden_layer.T, output_delta)
            self.bias2 += np.sum(output_delta, axis=0, keepdims=True)

            self.weights1 += np.dot(inputs, hidden_error.T)
            self.bias1 += np.sum(hidden_error, axis=0, keepdims=True)

# Creating an instance of the neural network
network = NeuralNetwork()

# Input data - weight and height of 5 people
inputs = np.array([[60, 170], [50, 160], [70, 180], [40, 150], [80, 190]])

# Desired outputs - gender of the person (0 - female, 1 - male)
targets = np.array([[1], [1], [1], [0], [1]])

# Training the network
network.train(inputs.T, targets, 10000)

# Predicting the gender for new data
test_inputs = np.array([[65, 175], [55, 165], [75, 185]])
test_outputs = network.feedforward(test_inputs.T)

print("Predicted gender:")
for i, output in enumerate(test_outputs):
    if output > 0.5:
        print(f"Person {i+1}: Male")
    else:
        print(f"Person {i+1}: Female")

And I get this error:
hidden_error = np.dot(self.weights2, output_delta) * sigmoid_derivative(hidden_layer)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (5,5) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

I understand, that i'm trying to multiply matrices of different dimensions but I've got no idea what else to do. If i had this kind of error in most cases transposing matrices helped (i think... at least an error message was gone), but in this case it won't help, so.. I'm stuck and I need your help.
